# Visual Studio Code Error using @prettier/plugin-xml "property engines is mandatory and must be of type object"

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm running Visual Studio Code (version 1.71.0) under Windows 10 (version 10.0.19044 Build 19044)

I've downloaded https://github.com/prettier/plugin-xml, unzipped it to C:\Users\RoysLaptop\.vscode\extensions\plugin-xml-main, and from VSC's Powershell Terminal executed "npm install --save-dev prettier @prettier/plugin-xml", yet when I try to execute "./node_modules/.bin/prettier --write '**/*.xml'", I get the following error:

[error] Unable to expand glob pattern: **/*.xml
[error] EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\RoysLaptop\Application Data'

When I look at the Extensions in Visual Studio Code (version 1.71.0) I see it grayed out with a red X next to it, and under the title of "@prettier/plugin-xml" I see "undefined_publisher" and error message:

property engines is mandatory and must be of type object

How do I install the Extension?

Thanks, Roy